# Springboot - The injection point has the following annotations: - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, dao

I am getting this error:
`

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:

Field questionDao in com.surbhi.quizapp.service.QuestionService required a bean of type 'com.surbhi.quizapp.dao.QuestionDao' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.surbhi.quizapp.dao.QuestionDao' in your configuration.
```

`
I have the following file structure and files.

**File structure:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jSrf.png

**QuestionService.java**

```
@Service
public class QuestionService {

  QuestionDao questionDao;

  public QuestionService(QuestionDao questionDao) {
    super();
    this.questionDao = questionDao;
  }

  public ResponseEntity<List<Question>> getAllQuestions() {
    try {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(questionDao.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ArrayList<>(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }

  public ResponseEntity<List<Question>> getQuestionsByCategory(
    String category
  ) {
    try {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(
        questionDao.findByCategory(category),
        HttpStatus.OK
      );
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ArrayList<>(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }

  public ResponseEntity<String> addQuestion(Question question) {
    questionDao.save(question);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("success", HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
}
```

**QuestionDao.java**

```
@Repository
public interface QuestionDao extends JpaRepository<Question, Integer> {
  List<Question> findByCategory(String category);

  @Query(
    value = "SELECT * FROM question q Where q.category=:category ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT :numQ",
    nativeQuery = true
  )
  List<Question> findRandomQuestionsByCategory(String category, int numQ);
}
```

I have also tried removing @Autowire and creating constructor but then that also didn't work and gave this error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.surbhi.quizapp.service.QuestionService required a bean of type 'com.surbhi.quizapp.dao.QuestionDao' that could not be found.

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.surbhi.quizapp.dao.QuestionDao' in your configuration.
```

What should I do, Also added

**@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={
"com.surbhi.quizapp.controller", "com.surbhi.quizapp.dao","com.surbhi.quizapp.model","com.surbhi.quizapp.service"})**

in main, but that doesn't work either.

Used @ComponentScan, doesn't work

**Main class file:**

```
@SpringBootApplication

@ComponentScan("com.surbhi.quizapp.dao")

public class QuizappApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuizappApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't post images of code.  Here's why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1847378

Comment: Have you tried adding @ComponentScan("com.surbhi.quizapp.dao") to your main application class?

Comment: Yes, Doesn't work either.

Comment: i will start by commenting findRandomQuestionsByCategory first if it work you know what is your problem

Comment: I commented findRandomQuestionsByCategory, but that doesn't change anything, giving same error.

Comment: Not sure whether you are using Maven/Gradle etc but potentially check in your pom.xml or build.gradle file for your dependencies. You should be using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa rather than spring-data-jpa. Just an idea

Comment: That's strange. When the scan path is specified with @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {""}), it works without any problems when reproduced with the questioner's package structure.

Move the QuizappApplication class to the top of the package and modify it to scan subpackages.

Comment: Add @EnableJpaRepositories on your application to scan for repositories. AFAIK jparepos are not discovered with component scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the package photo you uploaded, it appears that there are two `QuizappApplication` classes. (`com.surbhi.quizapp`, `com.surbhi.quizapp.service`)

Will the same problem occur if I remove the `QuizappApplication` class that exists in the `com.surbhi.quizapp.service` package and write it as follows?

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class QuizappApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuizappApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Additionally, the @Repository annotation is not required on the QuestionDao interface.